# Вытащить цифру из переменной в С#

Tags: c#, переменные

Есть переменная:

```
int thisbyte = 12345678;
```

Из него мне нужно по отдельности вытащить 12,3456,78.

Comment: Как пробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: По какому принципу нужно делить число?

Comment: Есть операторы `/` и `%` - деление и остаток от деления. Скорее всего, вам нужны они.

Comment: Если вам чисто для вывода, то смотрите [тут](http://mvblog.ru/archives/519/)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц в C# 6.0 можно писать `$"{...}"` вместо громоздкого `string.Format("{0}", ...)`

Comment: `thisbyte.ToString(@"##\,####\,##")` - не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если выполнить это

```
int thisbyte = 12345678;
var str = thisbyte.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0,2) + "," + str.Substring(2,4) + "," + str.Substring(6,2));
```

На выходе получим то, что вам надо

```
12,3456,78
```

Comment: Откуда такая уверенность что именно так надо?

Comment: @Monomax уверенности нет

Comment: @tym32167, Все подошло, это то что мне нужно.

Comment: В принципе можно было и `Console.WriteLine("12,3456,78");` :)

Comment: @yolosora это слишком просто :)